# higher-level newcommand or macro/command template generator (command templates)

Tags: macros

Below, notice how I essentially copy and paste the same two types of commands to create tiny variations on them; the two command ‘templates’ being:

```
% make a definition
%\def\defn#1{\textbf{Defn [#1]:}}
\newcommand{\defn}[1][]{%
   \ifthenelse{ \equal{#1}{} }
      {\textbf{Defn:}}
      {\textbf{Defn [#1]:}}
}
```

and

```
% make a highlight
\def\hi#1{\textbf{#1:}}
```

Instead of copying and pasting ad nauseam, I’d like to make 1 command template and then instantiate them all, like:

```
\newcommand{\defn}{ create_command_macro(template1, ‘Defn’) }
\newcommand{\prop}{ create_command_macro(template1, ‘Property’) }
```

and

```
\newcommand{\todo}{ create_command_macro(template2, ‘Todo’) }
\newcommand{\recall}{ create_command_macro(template2, ‘Recall’) }
```

**Is there a simple way to do this in Latex?** Essentially I’m thinking of equivalence of C macros.

If it becomes more complicated/obtuse then simply copying and pasting, them I’ll just stick to copying and pasting.

Thanks!!

**Output:**
[image]

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}

% used for more complex macros
\usepackage{ifthen}
% example:
% \newcommand{\dx}[1][]{%
%    \ifthenelse{ \equal{#1}{} }
%       {\ensuremath{\;\mathrm{d}x}}
%       {\ensuremath{\;\mathrm{d}#1}}
% }

% make a definition
%\def\defn#1{\textbf{Defn [#1]:}}
\newcommand{\defn}[1][]{%
   \ifthenelse{ \equal{#1}{} }
      {\textbf{Defn:}}
      {\textbf{Defn [#1]:}}
}

% make a property
%\def\prop#1{\textbf{Property [#1]:}}
\newcommand{\prop}[1][]{%
   \ifthenelse{ \equal{#1}{} }
      {\textbf{Property:}}
      {\textbf{Property [#1]:}}
}


% make a todo
\def\todo{\textbf{Todo: }}

% make a recall
\def\recall{\textbf{Recall: }}

\begin{document}

\\
\\
\defn{}\\
\defn{ASDF}\\
\\
\\
\todo\\
\note\\

\end{document}
```

Comment: apart from havig a constructor your question is not clear on the desired syntax. You show `\newcommand{\defn}[1][]{` so defing `\defn` to be have an optional argument so `\defn` or `\defn[ASDF]`  but you show `\defn{ASDF}` where ASDF is not an argument to defn, just simply text in a group following the command. As your image shows, DEFN is not typeset before the colon as `#1` would be in `Defn [#1]:`

Comment: Thanks for clarifications. I’m quite new to latex, and so I may have gotten the details wrong with those macro things :) However, regarding the desired syntax, I don’t have any desired syntax, just anything that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved by a form of partial application:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\templateone}{ m o }{%
    \textbf{#1\IfNoValueF{#2}{\ [#2]}:}%
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\defn}{}{\templateone{Defn}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\prop}{}{\templateone{Property}}

\NewDocumentCommand{\templatetwo}{ m }{%
    \textbf{#1: }%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\todo}{}{\templatetwo{Todo}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\recall}{}{\templatetwo{Recall}}
```

Using expl3 here since it lets you have optional arguments that are not #1.