# higher-level newcommand or macro/command template generator (command templates) but with *no* arguments during template creation

Tags: macros

[This question and answer is related and very helpful](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/649595/higher-level-newcommand-or-macro-command-template-generator-command-templates)  but I need help to also create templates which don’t take arguments at template creation time but then creates a macro that takes an argument?

**Example:**

```
\def\myStyleOne#1{\textbf{#1:}}
\def\myStyleTwo#1{\textit{#1:}}

\newcommand{\highlightWord}{ create_command_macro(myStyleOne)  }
\newcommand{\highlightSentence}{ create_command_macro(myStyleTwo)  }

% usage:
\highlightWord{asdf}
\highlightSentence{foo bar baz}
```

**Output:**

[image]

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\myStyleOne#1{\textbf{#1:}}
\def\myStyleTwo#1{\textit{#1:}}

% desired outcome for definition:
%\newcommand{\highlightWord}{ create_command_macro(myStyleOne)  }
%\newcommand{\highlightSentence}{ create_command_macro(myStyleTwo)  }

% current definition:
\def\highlightWord#1{\textbf{#1:}}
\def\highlightSentence#1{\textit{#1:}}


\begin{document}

\highlightWord{asdf}\\

\highlightSentence{foo bar baz}\\

\end{document}
```

Thanks for any kind help.

Comment: `\newcommand{\highlightWord}{\myStyleOne}  \newcommand{\highlightSentence}{\myStyleTwo}` is all you need

Comment: rather than say a MWE isn't needed it would have been simpler to provide one, why make people have to construct a test document?

Comment: Thanks so much David. I’ve put in the MWE and output as usual, now. Your solution works perfectly :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to declare arguments in your outer, advertised commands, so

```
\newcommand{\highlightWord}{\myStyleOne}
\newcommand{\highlightSentence}{\myStyleTwo}
```

---

```
\documentclass{article}

% not \def
\newcommand*\myStyleOne[1]{\textbf{#1:}}
\newcommand*\myStyleTwo[1]{\textit{#1:}}

\newcommand{\highlightWord}{\myStyleOne}
\newcommand{\highlightSentence}{\myStyleTwo}


\begin{document}

\highlightWord{asdf}% no badness 10000!\\

\highlightSentence{foo bar baz}% no badness 10000!\\

\end{document}
```

is all you need.